# Choroplet does not plot anything

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

i would like to display the world map based on the flux of people for some countries using plotly and Choroplet but it doesn't work and i don't understand why.

[This is my pandas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBvXz.png)

This code is supposed to plot the graph:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
flow = color_table.iloc[:,3]

data = [dict(type = 'choroplet',
         colorscale = 'Rainbow',
         location = color_table['COUNTRY_NAME_IT_y'],
         z = flow,
         text = color_table['COUNTRY_NAME_IT_x'],
         colorbar = dict(title = 'Flow of foreign users', titlefont=dict(size=25),tickfont=dict(size=18)),
        )]


layout = dict(title = 'Flow of foreign users',
         geo = dict(showframe = False,showcoastlines = False,projection = dict(type = 'equirectangular'))
         )

fig = dict(layout=layout, data=data)
iplot(fig,validate=False, filename='d3-world-map')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few changes I can finally launch your choropleth:

1.`type='choropleth'`, not `type='choroplet'`.

2.`'locations'`, not `'location'`.

3.If you want world map, then change `showcoastlines` to `True` - it's make map look more nice.

4.You can delete `projection` in `geo`, because `type=equirectangular` is value by default for this parameter.

I added `locationmode` and `scope` parameters with default value (but commented both). Those parameters should help you a lot when building a choropleth. For example, changing `scope='world'` to `scope='europe'` allowed you see only Europe map instead of world (in your data all countries from Europe, so that will make sense maybe). You can read more about those parameters [1](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#choropleth-locationmode) and [2](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-geo-scope). Also don't be afraid looking at full reference with all the parameters about choropleth and geo module [3](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#choropleth) and [4](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-geo).

Code:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

list1 = ['Romania', 'Russia', 'Austria']
list2 = ['ROU', 'RUS', 'AUT']
list3 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.3]

data = [dict(type='choropleth',
             colorscale='Rainbow',
             locations=list2,
             # locationmode='ISO-3',
             z=list3,
             text=list1,
             colorbar=dict(title='Flow of foreign users',
                           titlefont=dict(size=25),
                           tickfont=dict(size=18)),
             )]


layout = dict(title='Flow of foreign users',
              geo=dict(
                       showframe=False,
                       showcountries=True,
                       # scope='world',
                       ),
              )

fig = dict(layout=layout, data=data)
iplot(fig, validate=False, filename='d3-world-map')
```

Output:

[image: World Map Choropleth]